# What is the current notebook save event for the `EventHandler`?

Tags: eventhandler

Suppose I have an action like follows:

```
ClearAll[eventAction];
eventAction[]:=Module[{
    $previousPath,
    $todaysPath
},
    $previousPath=NotebookFileName[EvaluationNotebook[]];
    $todaysPath=FileNameJoin[{
        NotebookDirectory[],
        "NameChangingNotebook - "<>DateString[Today,{"Day","Month","YearShort"}]<>".nb"
    }];
    NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[],$todaysPath]
    DeleteFile[$previousPath]
];
```

How do I make this action execute whenever the notebook save command is sent?

```
DynamicModule[{},EventHandler[Null,{{"MenuCommand","Save"}:>(eventAction[])}]];
```

Comment: `FrontEndToken[EvaluationNotebook[], "Save"]` is not working here. Maybe some complex frontend knowledge is required for this task. You can try a binding with the shortkey like Ctrl + S in Windows.

Comment: Is NotebookEventActions the answer?

Comment: @Kuba sorry I don't have access to desktop notebook frontend right now. But if you can try and find out whether it works in the following command or any other command do let me know as well.

`SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],NotebookEventActions->{"WindowClose":>(eventAction[])}]`